# How to make Android layout size change animation smooth?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

I want to apply animation in the process of changing the size of the layout of Android.
As a result of using ValueAnimator and layout parameters, the animation seems to be very disconnected.
How to apply animation smoothly?

Attach some code. Thank you.

[image]

```
     var slideAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(beforeHeight,afterHeight).setDuration(150)
     var slideAnimator2 = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(beforeWidth,afterWidth).setDuration(150)

        binding.mainFragmentRoot.pivotY = 0F
        slideAnimator.addUpdateListener {
            (binding.mainFragmentCalendarLayout.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams).matchConstraintPercentHeight = it.animatedValue as Float
            binding.mainFragmentCalendarLayout.requestLayout()
            binding.mainFragmentCalendarLayout.invalidate()
        }

            binding.mainFragmentCalendarView.pivotX = 0F
        slideAnimator2.addUpdateListener {
            (binding.mainFragmentCalendarLayout.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams).matchConstraintPercentWidth = it.animatedValue as Float
        }
        var d = AnimatorSet()
        d.play(slideAnimator).with(slideAnimator2)
        d.start()
```

Comment: Can you provide a short video or GIF with your animation right now ?

Comment: I add my animation!

Comment: Have you considered using `MotionLayout`, as you are already using `ConstraintLayout`? The `requestLayout()` and `invalidate()` in your update listener look as though it would impact performance.

Comment: Coming home in 1 hour, if nobody answered I will help you but: did you already tried playing with some interpolators ? Maybe they could help

Comment: @PPartisan I don't try this yet, I will try use MotionLayout, Thanks!

Comment: @Davide I use LinearInterpolator, but not working T_T

Comment: MotionLayout is much more smooth and more flexible and easy. can you try it?